# Saving Object Literal to localStorage in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, local-storage

I'm trying to save this object into `$window.localStorage()`:

ctrl:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($window, $scope) {

$scope.initData = [
        {
            customer: 1,
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Doe"
        },
        {
            customer: 2,
            firstName: "Jane",
            lastName: "Doe"
        },
        {
            customerId: 3,
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Smith",

        }
      ];

// scopes

for(var i = 0; i < $scope.initData.length; ++i) {
           $window.localStorage.setItem(i, JSON.stringify($scope.initData[i]));
        }
});
```

But I get the values with keys as indexes.. I've also tried this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.initData.length; ++i) {
           $window.localStorage.setItem(i, Object.values($scope.initData[i]));
        }
```

and with `for..in`, but couldn't figure out what would be the best way.

Now, when I do `console.log(localStorage);` I have this as output:

```
0:"{"customer":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}"
1:"{"customer":2,"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Doe"}"
2:"{"customer":3,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith"}"
```

When I access the `0` as key, I get `customer` as value, and I need to get `1` as value. `customer` should be the key.

How can I achieve this? How can I convert this?

Comment: If you make `customer` as a key, there would be multiple keys with the same name. And this can not be done.

Comment: I know, that's why I've turned to arrays. How can I access `customer` now as a key reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the object `$scope.initData` completly to the `localStorage`, I don't see advantage of saving the `initData` objects seperatly. Load the customers from `localStorage` on application load, and save them on update. But don't work from the `localStorage`directly - I would use a `service` on top of that.

```
// Set localStorage item
localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify(dataObject));

// Retrieve the object from localStorage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('initData');

// console.log retrieved item
console.log('retrieved data Object: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Or you could change your key to something as this (taking the customer unique ID as reference), and not your loop counter :

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.initData.length; ++i) {
           $window.localStorage.setItem('customer-id' + $scope.initData[i].customer, JSON.stringify($scope.initData[i]));
        }
});
```

Comment: So, saving directly the `array of objects` into the `localStorage`, than using `JSON.parse(obj)` to interpolate it in the template?

Comment: Yes, either you interpolate it directly inside your `controller`, or use a `service` to group it as re-useable - and load it on application load.

Comment: I have no idea why I never thought of saving the entire object like this and then parsing it.. Just for a purpose of learning, in my example, is there a way to get the keys if they are in the values, like `0:"{"customer":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}"` ? So getting `"customer"` as key.

Comment: I suppose saving the whole object - would be much nicer yes :) You'll have to provide a custom filter to find the element with the specific id  (loop all elements and match the `customer` field to the value you are looking for - and return that item).